# Numpy Array value setting issues

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a data set that spans a certain length of time and data points for each of these time points. I would like to create a much more detailed timescale and fill the empty data points to zero. I wrote a piece of code to do this but it isn't doing what I want it to. I tried a sample case though and it seems to work. Below are the two codes.

This piece of code does not do what I want it to.

```
import numpy as np

TD_t = np.array([36000, 36500, 37000, 37500, 38000, 38500, 39000, 39500, 40000, 40500, 41000, 41500, 42000, 42500, 
             43000, 43500, 44000, 44500, 45000, 45500, 46000, 46500, 47000, 47500, 48000, 48500, 49000, 49500, 
             50000, 50500, 51000, 51500, 52000, 52500, 53000, 53500, 54000, 54500, 55000, 55500, 56000, 56500, 
             57000, 57500, 58000, 58500, 59000, 59500, 60000, 60500, 61000, 61500, 62000, 62500, 63000, 63500, 
             64000, 64500, 65000, 65500, 66000])

TD_d = np.array([-0.05466527, -0.04238242, -0.04477601, -0.02453717, -0.01662798, -0.02548617, -0.02339215, 
             -0.01186576, -0.0029057 , -0.01094671, -0.0095005 , -0.0190277 , -0.01215644, -0.01997112, 
             -0.01384497, -0.01610656, -0.01927564, -0.02119056, -0.011634  , -0.00544096, -0.00046568, 
             -0.0017769 , -0.0007341,  0.00193066,  0.01359107,  0.02054919,  0.01420335,  0.01550565,  
             0.0132394 ,  0.01371563,  0.01959774,  0.0165316 ,  0.01881992,  0.01554435,  0.01409003, 
             0.01898334,  0.02300266,  0.03045158,  0.02869013,  0.0238423 ,  0.02902356,  0.02568908,  
             0.02954539,  0.02537967,  0.02927247,  0.02138605,  0.02815635,  0.02733237,  0.03321588,  
             0.03063803,  0.03783137,  0.04110955,  0.0451221 ,  0.04646263,  0.04472884,  0.04935833,  
             0.03372911,  0.04031406,  0.04165237,  0.03940343,  0.03805504])

time = np.arange(0, 100001,1)
data = np.zeros_like(time)

for i in range(0, len(TD_t)):
    t = TD_t[i]
    data[t] = TD_d[i]
    print(i,t,TD_d[i],data[t])
```

But for some reason this code works.

```
import numpy
nums = numpy.array([0,1,2,3])
data = numpy.zeros_like(nums)
data[0] = nums[2]
data[0], nums[2]
```

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Just do `data = np.zeros(100001, dtype=TD_d.dtype); data[TD_t] = TD_d`, don't need the `time` variable. In general, you should almost never need to loop with NumPy, it's orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Do you know why the first method doesn't work though?

Comment: Like [tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588071/tom) said in the answer, `data` is created to be "like" `time`, which is created with `np.arange`, which (when given integer parameters) produces an array of integers; so `data` is of integer type. The values in `TD_d` are float, so NumPy casts them to integer when you assign them to `data`, and since they are all between -1 and 1 they get truncated to zero (so no changes). In the second snippet `nums` is integer, and so is `data`, so the assignment works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `dtype` of `data` is being set to `int64`, and so when you try to reassign one of the `data` elements, it gets rounded to zero.

Try changing the line to:

```
data = np.zeros_like(time, dtype=float)
```

and it should work (or use whatever `dtype` the `TD_d` array is)